# How to fill repeating values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the following shape:

```
>> dataset.shape
(1942,28)
```

I would like to create a new data frame `df_new` where I take the column names of `dataset` and make them repeating values in my `df_new`.

This is an example:

```
>> dataset.columns
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want my `df_new` to look like:

```
    column_name 
 0       a
 1       b
 2       c
 3       d
 4       a
 5       b
 6       c
 7       d
 8       a
 9       b
 10      c
 11      d
 .      .
 .      . 
(until the length of the array)
```

Currently when I write the below piece of code, I don't get the desired answer.

```
>> df_new = pd.DataFrame({0:np.arange(0,28).repeat(dataset_ts.shape[1])})
      0
0     0
1     0
2     0
.     .
.     . 
.     .
27    0
28    1
29    1
30    1
.     .
.     .
```

Comment: `np.tile(df.columns, length)[:length]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
cols = dataset.columns            
length = dataset_ts.shape[0]      

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'new': np.tile(cols, length)})
print (df_new)
   new
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    a
5    b
6    c
7    d
8    a
9    b
10   c
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) + [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import pandas as pd

from itertools import cycle, islice

length = 1942
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

result = pd.DataFrame({'new': list(islice(cycle(data), length))})

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     new
0      a
1      b
2      c
3      d
4      a
...   ..
1937   b
1938   c
1939   d
1940   a
1941   b

[1942 rows x 1 columns]
```

As an alternative you could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) + cycle in a list comprehension:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'new': [e for _, e in zip(range(length), cycle(data))] })
```